# How can I list products that I added to the basket when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I have some product IDs in local storage. Using these IDs I'm trying to list products that were added to the basket. However, when I move to the basket page, products are not listed, unless I for example delete a line of code and save the file again.

```
function Basket() {

  const [proArr, setProArr] = useState<string[]>([])
  const [prd, setPrd] = useState<Product[]>([])

useEffect(() => {

  const stArr = localStorage.getItem("basket")
  if(stArr){
   const arr:string[] = JSON.parse(stArr) as string[]
   setProArr(arr)
  }
  const arr2 = Object.assign([],prd)
 { proArr.map((item,index)=>
  singleProduct(item).then((res)=>{
    arr2.push(res.data)
  }).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err.message)
  })
  )}
 setPrd(arr2)
}, [])

  return (
    <>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Product Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>               
           { 
           prd.map((item,index) =>(   
            <tr key={index}>
                <td> 
                  <div className="col-2">
                  <img src={item.images[0]} className='img-thumbnail' />
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>{item.brand}</td>
                <td>{item.price}$</td>
                <td>{item.stock}</td>
              </tr> 
            ))   
           }            
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}

export default Basket;
```

I get my products list from DummyJSON and I am trying to add products to the basket.

For this, I am saving the IDs of products to local storage. I am trying to access them from the basket page and I am sending them to the service to list them. However, they are not showing up when I visit the basket page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you so much for edit my sharing. I will be more careful in my next questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that the `prd` variable does not include the correct data when you show the page. We can assume then, that the issue stems from the piece of code that loads the correct data into said varaible. That would be your `useEffect`, I believe the rest of your code is irrelevant.

I rewrote your code so it's easier for me to understand, all I did was rename the variables and format it so it looks nice.

```
const [productStrings, setProductStrings] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [products, setProducts] = useState <Product[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const basket = localStorage.getItem("basket");
    if (basket) {
        const parsedBasket: string[] = JSON.parse(basket) as string[];
        setProductStrings(parsedBasket);
    }
    const currentProducts = Object.assign([], products);
    productStrings.map((product, index) =>
        singleProduct(product)
        .then((response) => {
            currentProducts.push(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
        })
    );

    setProducts(currentProducts);
}, []);
```

So I Obviously can't test this code to check what might be causing the issue, but I can onlu assume the issue is the fact that you asynchronously fetch the product. So by the time this async line runs: `currentProducts.push(response.data);` (or `arr2.push(res.data)` in your code), this other - synchronous - line, has already run: `setProducts(currentProducts);` with empty data.

To fix this, you can simply move the second line to after the async code has finished running, to do that, I would move the entire thing into an asynchronous function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const basket = localStorage.getItem("basket");
    if (basket) {
        const parsedBasket: string[] = JSON.parse(basket) as string[];
        setProductStrings(parsedBasket);
    }
    const currentProducts = Object.assign([], products);
    const asyncCallback = async() => {
        for (let productStr of productStrings) {
            try {
                const product = await singleProduct(productStr);
                currentProducts.push(product.data);
            } catch (err: any) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        }
        setProducts(currentProducts);
    };

    asyncCallback();
}, []);
```

Again, I can't be sure if this is the actual root of your error as I can't run this code, so please let me know if this helps or if the issue persists ^_^

Comment: Hi ! First of all, thank you very much for your interest and help. I applied your codes but the problem persists.

Comment: Oh, that sucks! I have another idea, it may be that `productStrings` hasn't been updated by the time you are running the for loop, if that's the case, moving everything before the Object.assign into a new useEffect hook, and then adding a `productStrings` dependency to the original hook might do the trick.
First things first, could you add this line to before the `setProducts(...)`line?
`console.log({basket, currentProducts, productStrings});`
This way we can see how many times the useEffect hook runs, and when nothing appears in the UI as well as when it does work.

Comment: I moved everything before the Object.assing into a new useEffect but nothing changed. It's so silly that when I delete something and write again then products show up. So it looks like render problem.